# ORA-00936 : missing expressions for IN clause

Tags: oracle

```
 select * from students where s_id IN (:sIds);
public List<Integer> getStudents(@Param("userId") Integer sIds);
```

where
sIds => List of student ids

Comment: What is a format of sIds variable? If the format is a string then you can use execute immediate for your query. Read about dynamic sql https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#i13057

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a single bind variable to hold multiple values and use it as an in-list. Depending on the type of the s_id column you can do something like this (here I suppose :sIds is a comma-separated list of integers):

```
select * 
from students
where s_id in (select regexp_substr(:sIds, '[0-9]+',1,level) 
from val
connect by level<regexp_count(:sIds,',')+2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be this:

```
SQL> select * from emp
  2  where empno in
  3    (select * from table(sys.odcinumberlist(7369, 7499, 7521)));

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE          SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-12-1980        800                    20
      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-02-1981       1600        300         30
      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-02-1981       1250        500         30

SQL>
```

where `7369, 7499, 7521` represents values you'd enter into `sIds`